# What do I need to know about the "weird" Galaxy S Vibrant emergency call handling?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, calls, samsung-vibrant, emergency-calls

Vibrant support was dropped from CyanogenMod after 7.1 (Gingerbread) due to [issues](http://pocketnow.com/android/cyanogenmod-drops-vibrant-911-support-its-achilles-heel) with [failed 911 calls](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/32208-911-doesnt-work-on-vibrant-but-works-on-other-galaxy-s-models/).  I flashed 7.1 a bit before this was made known, and have since reverted to my stock-based ROM.  This is obviously a bit concerning and I have a few remaining questions:

- Did flashing CM damage anything?  (I.e., will emergency calls work now that I'm on a different ROM?)
- Can this happen with stock-based ROMs?
- Was it all emergency calls, or just 911?
- Is it related to Gingerbread?
- Has it been fixed in CM? I've seen a few things both ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official announcement on the CM forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/forum-0/announcement-19-cm-vibrant-support/) states:

- The issue was in the [RIL](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/telephony.html) code, which is just typical code and libraries packaged in the ROM (e.g. `/system/lib/libril.so`, for example). The CM team recommended installing a Samsung ROM noting that any Samsung ROM is fine and any AOSP ROM would have issues. There's no permanent damage since the RIL code was replaced when you reflashed.
- They specifically cited the issue was related to closed-source RIL code, so this wouldn't happen with a stock ROM unless Samsung **severely** borked their RIL code.
- Only 911 was listed as a problem, but I don't know (and neither have the CM team ever stated) if other emergency numbers were affected.
- Official support for the Vibrant didn't occur until 7.1, which was Gingerbread. It's really hard to say if older versions were affected, but I would assume yes (if they exist somewhere still).
- The announcement states that the issue was fixed and the Vibrant is officially supported at this point.

Comment: Oh duh, I knew it wasn't supported before, and I know I've seen the original version of that announcement but couldn't find it again.  Glad they fixed it ... very different from the previous "unresolvable" status.

Comment: @MatthewRead I can't believe you still have a vibrant and that you are still running TouchWiz. I didn't even revert when the e911 issue was identified. I am now just waiting for official cm9 support. The vibrant also now has a new maintainer for CM since this issue was resolved as I believe the original maintainer had the device, but did not have a working SIM for it as he is not in the US.

Comment: @RyanConrad I've been extremely happy with Bionix, and CM7.1 was really bad. Definitely going to try CM9 though now that I know I can.